# How do I use an image returned from an MVC controller in HTML?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC project, that has a controller method that returns an image...

```
public ActionResult SpeakerImage(int id) {
  Speaker speaker = _speakersServiceLogic.GetByID(id);
  if (speaker != null) {
    return File(speaker.Picture, "image/jpg");
  }
  return null;
}
```

How do I use this in an HTML img tag? I know I can hard-code the src attribute...

`<img src="/Speakers/SpeakerImage/@Model.ID" />`

...but this will break if the controller action is moved.

I was wondering if there is a better way to do this. To create a link, I can use Html.ActionLink, which will create the HTML for me. Is there something similar for `<img>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Url.Action`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) to generate the URL for you:

```
<img src='@Url.Action("Speakers", "SpeakerImage", new { ID = @Model.ID} )' />
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew it had to be something simple, but I just couldn't work out what! I'll get there eventually :)